# Why does Thymeleaf code not work in the head section of HTML but works fine in the body

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, wro4j

I am using wro4j to minify static content.  However, when I am in my development environment I would like to use the uncompressed versions of my JS and CSS files.

To put it into context, I am using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf.

This code does not work inside the `<head></head>` of my HTML:

```
<th:block th:if="${@environment.getActiveProfiles()[0] != 'development'}">
    <link th:href="@{/wro4j/compressed.css}" rel="stylesheet"></link>
</th:block>
<th:block th:if="${@environment.getActiveProfiles()[0] == 'development'}">
    <link th:href="@{/css/uncompressed.css}" rel="stylesheet"></link>
</th:block>
```

What I see from the code above in the source of my HTML is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wro4j/compressed.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/uncompressed.css" />
```

Surely the only css that should be included is uncompressed.css as I have set my profile to be *development* in 'application.yml'.

However if I were to do something like the following in the `<body></body>` it would work perfectly as I expect:

```
<th:block th:if="${@environment.getActiveProfiles()[0] == 'development'}">
    <div th:text="${@environment.getActiveProfiles()[0]}"></div>
</th:block>
<th:block th:if="${@environment.getActiveProfiles()[0] != 'development'}">
    <div th:text="'WHAT THE HECK!' + ${@environment.getActiveProfiles()[0]"></div>
</th:block>
```

Having set my spring profile to *development* in `application.yml`, what I would expect to see from the latter block is "development" and not "WHAT THE HECK! development" and that is exactly what I see. So why is the same code not behaving as I expect in the head section of my HTML.

What am I missing?

Comment: See [this bug](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/246). You can simply use `th:if` on the `link` directly, and use `th:unless` on the other one.

Comment: @BoristheSpider You should post this as a solution so it can be accpeted

Comment: @hamster An alternate option to changing the filename for dev & production would be to build the files differently based on environment.  Tools such as Gulp or Webpack work great.  They can be integrated into Maven & Gradle projects as well.  A little bit beyond the scope of this question, but I thought I'd mention it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Boris's comment on my question, the solution is to use Thymeleaf version 3. However as a workaround this is what I have done for the time being:

```
<link th:if="${@environment.getActiveProfiles()[0] != 'development'}"  th:href="@{/wro4j/all.css}" rel="stylesheet" />

<script  th:if="${@environment.getActiveProfiles()[0] == 'development'}" th:src="@{/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
```